# iOS detecting distance between user's face and device using front camera

Tags: ios, camera, core-image, front-camera

Right now i am developing an app for testing human eye by reading letters and symbols, for that the user have to maintain 2 feet distance from his device. So I need to detect distance between human face and ios device using front camera.

**Regarding this i have some doubts to clarify**

1. For detecting human face i planned to use core-image framework. In that is it possible to detect the human face in background without camera UI?
2. For calculating distance i planned to use the below formula

   `distance = focal length * real height of object * camera frame height /(image height * sensor height)`
3. And i have seen few apps in app store, those are using back camera to calculate the distance between the device and object. So i have little bit confusion is it possible to work it out using front camera.

Please help me, how to acheive this or tell me your suggestion whether it is a right way or not.

Comment: a "little" too late, but for future visitors, check this repo https://github.com/evermeer/EVFaceTracker